# changing communities domain name

Tags: community, configuration, partner-communities

Currently within the Salesforce Partner Community configuration settings I can find no way to change the domain name. However, if I change the brand/name of my company, how can I change my communities domain name to reflect the new name, e.g., CompanyName.com changes to NewCompanyName.com?
If I cannot change the domain name and therefore I need to set up a new one, do I have to set everything up again, is there a way of migrating everything across form the old to the new so that users don't loose functionality or history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support organization has the ability to change the force.com domain name with the proper validation. You can log a case. Keep in mind any domain name change might take up to 24 hours to be effective and the old domain name won't be valid.

Comment: would this cover in my example above?

Comment: Yes @Bartley, This would cover your scenario too. You can ask the salesforce.com support to change the Unique Chatter Network Subdomain from old value to new value.The update will generally take around 1 hour to update with downtime for the customer’s domain, but may last up to 48 hours

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't change the domain name. As soon as it is configured it cannot be changed. check also the documentation [here](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf) . On page 7 it explicitly states:

> Important
>   :
>   Keep in mind that you can
>   ’
>   t change the domain name after you save it.

However, it may worth contacting Salesforce support and kindly ask them

Comment: indeed I have read that too, however there are times when things can be changed, I will update my question to ask about an alternative solution in the event it cannot be changed

Comment: I would definitely try contacting Salesforce support !!!